# How can I extract struct type names from a .dll?

Tags: reflection, c#-3.0

Can we exctract the structure's name from .dll using System.Reflection?
Please suggest some links.

```
struct MyStruct // <-- this name i wanna to find from .dll using Reflection
{
    private int length;
    private int breadth;
    public int Area(int length,int breadth)
    {
        return length*breadth;
    }
}
```

Comment: An assembly can contain an 'unlimited' number of types. Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "the structure name"?

Comment: Sorry already i got the Solution from other source.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of all types from an assembly (*.dll*) by calling the [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) method. The name for each type can be accessed from the [`Type.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

Check the links

[Assembly.GetTypes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)

[System.Reflection Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx)

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)